# Как проверить тип данных в пустом поле JSON

Tags: json, postman

Есть поля в респонсе

```
"full_name": "Customer Laster",
"photo": "",
"gender": null,
```

пишу код для проверки

```
pm.expect(data.data.full_name).to.be.a('string');
pm.expect(data.data.photo).to.be.a('null');
pm.expect(data.data.gender).to.be.a('string');
```

и пишет ошибку

```
 AssertionError: expected '' to be a null
```

Comment: Есть онлайн инструменты для проверки JSON. Следует ими воспользоваться и тогда с автопарсингом не должно быть проблем.

Comment: какие именно инструменты? А то я пишу свои тесты в сервисы для проверки а там выдает ошибку. Даже пишу туда тесты которые предлагает Postman

Comment: Да хотя бы https://jsonlint.com/, который находится первым по запросу "json online check". И пока он не выдаст, что всё правильно - правьте JSON. А потом уже с другими языками ковыряться.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку

Comment: да без проблем. Самому однажды пришлось исправлять JSON. Ещё рекомендую почитать о JSON как о стандарте. Ссылки не дам, ибо сам не помню, даже запрос.

Comment: я тесты просто никогда не писал, а тут сказали для апи надо написать автотесты... вот сижу, башка кипит

Comment: Тогда только изучение синтаксиса и, временно, ручная проверка. Я два года назад с JSON заморачивался, поэтому прямо подсказать не могу.

Comment: ехх) надо учить  json
спасибо!